# Remove the lines from a document

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, business-intelligence

Goal:
Display the result without using any line between column and row

Problem:
I can't remove these line

The picture below is taken in preview mode

// Fullmetalboy

[image]

Comment: What line? Between column and row? Where?

Comment: Tichodroma: Yes, it should be between row and column. Where? what do you mean?
aF: Result? what do you mean. The result is being displayed in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the textbox properties for each cell of the grid, just make sure you set the BorderWidth property to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Due to very limited info in the question maybe try Results-to-text instead of Results-to-grid?

Answer (score 0):

I think that we need more info here... are you showing these results in a HTML page, through some dynamic language (ASP, PHP, Ruby)? or are you using reporting tools like Crystal Dynamics?

If you're doing in HTML, I guess the css rule `border-collapse:collapse` on the table would do the trick

Comment: Look at the tags. He's using reporting services.